# How to test Li-Po battery capacity?

Tags: lipo

Is there a straight forward way to test and so confirm the mAh capacity of a LIPO battery?  I just bought a 15000mAh battery and would like to confirm that specification.

Rupert

Comment: What did google say?

Comment: What voltage is the battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
The capacity will very based on a few conditions, namely the load seen by the battery, the minimum voltage your system will need to continue operation and the battery's age. Typically the best way to measure this is to use a programmable load and track the charge coming out of the battery under a constant discharge current. Check this [appnote](http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/DC_Electronic_Load_Application_Note.pdf) out

Comment: Thanks, I checked app note.  As above do I just need to connect battery across input and output of programmable load eg LM317?

Answer (score 3):

Charge the battery fully. Use a constant current load such as an LM317 configured as a current load to discharge at say a 0.05C rate. When the per cell voltage (not battery voltage) reaches 3.2 volts, stop the test and record the total time. Multiply the time in hours by the current of the constant current load and you have the AH capacity.

Note that using a resistor as a load does not give accurate results unless you take frequent voltage readings during the test at regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks.  So do I just need to connect the 15000mAh battery across the input and output of the LM317?  Is it dangerous to short such a big battery?  I'll do it on breadboard and may accidentally cross wires.

Comment: No! The LM317 needs to be wired as a constant current load of around 500 milliamps. It will need adequate heatsinking. Consult a datasheet. Protect against fire and explosion during the test.